# Accessing values from [Object][Object] data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data looks like this:

```
var freqData=[
    {State: 'B1',freq:{ segment1:0.024, segment2:0, segment3:0.07, segment4:0.032, segment5:0.021 }},
    {State: 'B2',freq:{ segment1:0.034, segment2:0.008, segment3:0.024, segment4:0.028, segment5:0.024 }}
  ];
```

How do you access an individual segment name (i.e. "segment1")?

I have tried:

```
freqData.State.freq but this doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Since `freqData` is a JavaScript array, you need to first iterate over that array in order to access individual segments:

```
freqData.forEach(function(data) {
    var s1 = data.freq.segment1;
    // do something with segment1 data
});
```

Or you can also use the more traditional way of iterating over arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i < freqData.length; i++) {
    var s1 = freqData[i].freq.segment1;
    // do something with segment1 data
});
```

And if you need just the segment names in the `freq` sub-array, you can access them like this:

```
freqData.forEach(function(data) {
    var segmentNames = Object.keys(data.freq);
    // do something with the segment names
});
```

Comment: So this gets me all segments like this .. segment1, segment2, segment3 etc. But how can I select the segment that is being hovered over? Thats what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
Object.keys(freqData[0].freq); //Returns ["segment1", "segment2", "segment3", "segment4", "segment5"]
```